# Why does this fibonacci sequence work? Can someone help me?

Tags: python-3.x

Python beginner problem
(I am a beginner programmer)
So I was making a simple Fibonacci sequence generator and I made a working version, but I'm confused about how it works. In the code (lines 8-9), the first number (0) is being made the new value of the second value (1). But then that should make all the other numbers 0 as well, but it seems like the defining process is backward. Generally, the new value is on the left of the equal sign and the old value is on the right. But then that means everything should turn to 0. But actually, every number turns to 0 if I try to re-define the variables in the regular way (b = a; c = b). Why is this? I've attached my code at the bottom.

```
def seq_loop():
    a = 0
    b = 1

    for i in range(15):
        print(a)
        c = a + b
        a = b
        b = c

print(seq_loop())
```

Comment: What have you tried to check what this code does? If you set `b = 1`, why do you expect that it sets this variable to 0?

Comment: _"Generally, the new value is on the left of the equal sign and the old value is on the right."_ Seems like you have a major misunderstanding/incorrect assumption about how the `=` operator works, and that's the cause of your confusion.

Answer (score 0):

Have a good look at your code.  Walk through it, and write down a,b and c in each iteration (or if you know how to use a debugger, set a break point in the loop te verify your variable's values).  You'll see that your thinking is not right:  in your first iteration: `a = b` is equivalent to `a = 1` and `b = c` is equivalent to `b = 1 + 1`.
I am not sure that your interpretation of assignments is correct: An assignment goes right to left.  The value (of the variable) on the right side of `=` is assigned to the variable on the left side of `=`

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you are asking, but a good way to understand code is to simply execute it by hand with pen&paper and keep a list of all the variables in scope and their current values. So, let's do that now.

In the first line, we define and initialize the variable `a` to the value `0`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 0 }`.

In the second line, we define and initialize the variable `b` to the value `1`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 0; b = 1 }`.

In the first line of the loop, we print the current value of the variable `a`, which we can look up in our variable list is `0`. We haven't assigned any variables, so our variables in scope are still unchanged: `{ a = 0; b = 1 }`. And the console looks like this:

```
0
```

In the second line of the loop, we define and initialize the variable `c` to the result of evaluating the expression `a + b`. We have to dereference the two variables, i.e. look up their values in our list, and their values are `0` and `1`. `0 + 1` is `1`, which means we initialize `c` to `1`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 0; b = 1; c = 1 }`.

In the third line of the loop, we assign the variable `a`. The value we assign to the variable `a` is the current value of the variable `b`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `b` is `1`, which means we assign `1` to `a`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 1; c = 1 }`.

In the fourth line of the loop, we assign the variable `b`. The value we assign to the variable `b` is the current value of the variable `c`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `c` is `1`, which means we assign `1` to `b`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 1; c = 1 }`.

*After* the fourth line of the loop, the variable `c` goes out of scope. Our variables in scope and their values are now `{ a = 1; b = 1 }`.

As you can see, we started the first iteration of the loop with `{ a = 1; b = 0 }` but after the first iteration of the loop, we have `{ a = 1; b = 1 }`, which is what we start the second iteration of the loop with. It is important that something has changed here, otherwise each iteration of the loop would do the same thing, and we would always get the same result.

So, let's look at the second iteration of the loop.

In the first line of the loop, we print the current value of the variable `a`, which we can look up in our variable list is `1`. We haven't assigned any variables, so our variables in scope are still unchanged: `{ a = 1; b = 1 }`. And the console looks like this:

```
0
1
```

In the second line of the loop, we define and initialize the variable `c` to the result of evaluating the expression `a + b`. We look up their values in our list, and their values are `1` and `1`. `1 + 1` is `2`, which means we initialize `c` to `2`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 1; c = 2 }`.

In the third line of the loop, we assign the variable `a`. The value we assign to the variable `a` is the current value of the variable `b`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `b` is `1`, which means we assign `1` to `a`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 1; c = 2 }`.

In the fourth line of the loop, we assign the variable `b`. The value we assign to the variable `b` is the current value of the variable `c`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `c` is `2`, which means we assign `2` to `b`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 2 }`.

*After* the fourth line of the loop, the variable `c` goes out of scope. Our variables in scope and their values are now `{ a = 1; b = 2 }`.

Now for the third iteration.

In the first line of the loop, we print the current value of the variable `a`, which we can look up in our variable list is `1`. We haven't assigned any variables, so our variables in scope are still unchanged: `{ a = 1; b = 2 }`. And the console looks like this:

```
0
1
1
```

In the second line of the loop, we define and initialize the variable `c` to the result of evaluating the expression `a + b`. We look up their values in our list, and their values are `1` and `2`. `1 + 2` is `3`, which means we initialize `c` to `3`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 1; b = 2; c = 3 }`.

In the third line of the loop, we assign the variable `a`. The value we assign to the variable `a` is the current value of the variable `b`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `b` is `2`, which means we assign `2` to `a`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 2; b = 2; c = 3 }`.

In the fourth line of the loop, we assign the variable `b`. The value we assign to the variable `b` is the current value of the variable `c`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `c` is `3`, which means we assign `3` to `b`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 2; b = 3; c = 3 }`.

*After* the fourth line of the loop, the variable `c` goes out of scope. Our variables in scope and their values are now `{ a = 2; b = 3 }`.

And this is the fourth iteration of the loop.

In the first line of the loop, we print the current value of the variable `a`, which we can look up in our variable list is `2`. We haven't assigned any variables, so our variables in scope are still unchanged: `{ a = 2; b = 3 }`. And the console looks like this:

```
0
1
1
2
```

In the second line of the loop, we define and initialize the variable `c` to the result of evaluating the expression `a + b`. We look up their values in our list, and their values are `2` and `3`. `2 + 3` is `5`, which means we initialize `c` to `5`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 2; b = 3; c = 5 }`.

In the third line of the loop, we assign the variable `a`. The value we assign to the variable `a` is the current value of the variable `b`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `b` is `3`, which means we assign `3` to `a`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 3; b = 3; c = 5 }`.

In the fourth line of the loop, we assign the variable `b`. The value we assign to the variable `b` is the current value of the variable `c`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `c` is `5`, which means we assign `5` to `b`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 3; b = 5; c = 5 }`.

*After* the fourth line of the loop, the variable `c` goes out of scope. Our variables in scope and their values are now `{ a = 3; b = 5 }`.

Let's do one last iteration of the loop.

In the first line of the loop, we print the current value of the variable `a`, which we can look up in our variable list is `3`. We haven't assigned any variables, so our variables in scope are still unchanged: `{ a = 3; b = 5 }`. And the console looks like this:

```
0
1
1
2
3
```

In the second line of the loop, we define and initialize the variable `c` to the result of evaluating the expression `a + b`. We look up their values in our list, and their values are `3` and `5`. `3 + 5` is `8`, which means we initialize `c` to `8`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 3; b = 5; c = 8 }`.

In the third line of the loop, we assign the variable `a`. The value we assign to the variable `a` is the current value of the variable `b`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `b` is `5`, which means we assign `5` to `a`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 5; b = 5; c = 8 }`.

In the fourth line of the loop, we assign the variable `b`. The value we assign to the variable `b` is the current value of the variable `c`. So, we look at our variable list, and we see that the current value of `c` is `8`, which means we assign `8` to `b`. Our variables in scope and their values are `{ a = 5; b = 8; c = 8 }`.

*After* the fourth line of the loop, the variable `c` goes out of scope. Our variables in scope and their values are now `{ a = 5; b = 8 }`.

I hope it is somewhat clearer now.

One thing that is very important in programming is *naming*. Good names should be *intention-revealing*. In this case, none of the names are very good: what does the name `a` tell you about what the intent of the programmer is? The same goes for `b`, `c`, and `i`. `seq_loop` is also not very intention-revealing, i.e. what does this function actually do? It prints the Fibonacci sequence. How can I tell from the name that it prints the Fibonacci sequence? Well, I simply can't!

So, here is the code with some better names, which should clear up some confusion:

```python
def print_fibonacci_sequence():
    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    for _ in range(15):
        print(previous)

        after    = previous + current
        previous = current
        current  = after


print(print_fibonacci_sequence())
```

You might ask yourself "How is `_` a more intention-revealing name than `i`?" The reason is that `_` has a well-known meaning in the Python community: it is used as the name for a variable that is being ignored. Which is exactly what we are doing in this case.

Also, why `after` and not `next`? `next` is already defined in Python and it is considered bad style to shadow or even worse redefine Python builtins.

There are a couple of other oddities in the code. For example, the function prints the elements of the Fibonacci sequence and it doesn't return anything. And then you call the function and print the result of the call … but there is no result because the function doesn't return anything! Renaming the function to have `print` in its name so that it is *clear* that it doesn't return anything but prints it, makes that mistake more obvious:

```python
print(print_fibonacci_sequence())
```

You can immediately see that you print something which prints something, which makes no sense. It should just be

```python
print_fibonacci_sequence()
```

Another oddity is that the function always prints the first 15 terms of the Fibonacci sequence. Usually, you would want to let the caller decide how many terms to print. Maybe the caller only needs 3? Maybe 20? So, let's do that:

```python
def print_fibonacci_sequence(number_of_elements):
    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    for _ in range(number_of_elements):
        print(previous)

        after    = previous + current
        previous = current
        current  = after


print_fibonacci_sequence(15)
```

Speaking of letting the caller decide what to do, what if the caller doesn't want to print the Fibonacci sequence? What if the caller wants to format it as HTML or insert it into an Excel table?

You should *always* separate computation from input/output. So, in this case, instead of printing the Fibonacci sequence, we will *return* the Fibonacci sequence, and then the caller can print it if they want to:

```python
def fibonacci_sequence(number_of_elements):
    fibonacci_sequence = []

    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    for _ in range(number_of_elements):
        fibonacci_sequence.append(previous)

        after    = previous + current
        previous = current
        current  = after

    return fibonacci_sequence


print(fibonacci_sequence(15))
```

Actually, if you think about it, having the caller pass the number of terms as an argument is still somewhat restrictive. What if the caller doesn't want the first `n` terms, but the first terms smaller than `n`? In that case, they would have to compute the Fibonacci sequence first to see how many terms there are smaller than `n` and then ask for that number of terms of the Fibonacci sequence, which obviously defeats the purpose of having the function in the first place.

The best solution for the caller would be to produce an infinite number of terms and let the caller decide which condition to use to decide how many terms to take:

```python
def fibonacci_sequence():
    previous = 0
    current  = 1

    while True:
        yield previous

        after    = previous + current
        previous = current
        current  = after
```

Now you can use it like this:

```python
from itertools import islice, takewhile

first_15_terms = islice(fibonacci_sequence(), 15)
terms_less_than_100 = takewhile(lambda term: term < 100, fibonacci_sequence())
```

And you can decide what to do with the result. For example print it:

```python
for term in first_15_terms:
    print(term)

for term in terms_less_than_100:
    print(term)
```

Or you can turn it into a list:

```python
list_of_first_15_terms = list(first_15_terms)
list_of_terms_less_than_100 = list(terms_less_than_100)
```

And many other things.

This is a general principle in programming, software engineering, and API design: not only separate input/output from computation, but also break up the computation into separate parts for producing values, consuming values, transforming values, filtering values, representing values as strings (to be output later), parsing string representations into values (coming in from the outside), and so on.

In one sentence, we could say: separate the things that change.